What does the suffix "A“ mean on specific PW1100G(A) engines?
Some time ago I tried to find out what the difference between a PW1100G and a PW1100GA exactly is. I am asking this question here because there seems to be no information online that could be useful for me to find this out.

Where do you find references to a PW1100GA? It doesn't seem to exist.

I already have seen it on a a321neo A/C status page when I visited the flight deck (PW1133GA), so it does exist and that is what I meant before, there is nothing about it online…

It probably refers to "Advantage" series, PW1100G-JM Advantage. About 1% more thrust and uses a little less fuel. Certified in 2023 and entered service in 2024.
https://prd-sc102-cdn.rtx.com/-/media/pw/products/commercial-jet-engines/pratt-and-whitney-gtf/family/files/pw_gtf_pc_pw1100g-jm_2021_web.pdf

as you can see on this specs, the ,,advantage“ version of the PW1100G is signed with /2, whereas there are non-advantage models with the suffix ,,A“.
